# How to keep DateTime.now() static so it doesn't update time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to print a timestamp to the screen and eventually send it in a http post request... problem is currently I am displaying the timestamp on the screen and it is updating every millisecond so it displays the current time. Is there a way to make it static so it does not update every millisecond with the current time? So instead it just shows the time the widget was rendered on the screen?

```
// Displays receive data to user
List<Container> CollectedData(BuildContext context, bool hasData, String deviceID, List decoded, Color headerColor, Color textColor) {
  // Determine size of screen
  var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  // Get timestamp in UTC
  final timestamp = DateTime.now().toUtc().toString();
```

Comment: where are you calling the CollectedData? in build method?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.now()` by definition returns the current time.  If you don't want the current time, don't call `DateTime.now()` directly.  Store its value in a variable somewhere and use that; then *you* control when that variable is updated.

Or, if you just want a `DateTime` that is less precise, you either could:

- Create a new `DateTime` object that discards milliseconds and microseconds:

  ```dart
  var now = DateTime.now();
  now = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second);
  ```
- Don't output milliseconds and microseconds when converting the `DateTime` to a `String`:

  ```dart
  import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

  ...
  var timestamp = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
  ```